# Unable to save into postgresql using symfony and doctrine with its association objects or table?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have to save a `ticket` with `ticket_attachments`,`ticket_comments` and `ticket_status_history`.  I will persist only `ticket` object but want to save attachments,comments and history. I am using doctrine and symfony and annotations.

I have created 3 array collections in `ticket` with mappedBy and cascade remove and persist. And used inversedBy in attachments, comments and history. But after persisting and flush only `ticket` is being saved but other objects i.e. attachments,comments and historys are not saving. But shows **No Error**.

**Ticket.php**

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TicketAttachments", mappedBy="ticket", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $attachments;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TicketComments", mappedBy="ticket", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $comments;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TicketStatusHistory", mappedBy="ticket", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $historys;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->attachments = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->historys = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

**History, Comments and Attachments.php**

```
/**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Ticket
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Ticket", inversedBy="historys")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ticket_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $ticket;
```

All have it's setter and getter. Where is the problem?

Comment: in Ticket.php for attachments `public function setTicketAttachmentsList($attachments){
        $this->attachments = $attachments;
        return $this;
    }`  and in attachments public function setTicket(\AppBundle\Entity\Ticket $ticket = null)
    {
        $this->ticket = $ticket;

        return $this;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting them to each other? As in:

```
public function addToHistories($history) {
   $this->historys[] = $history;
   $history->setTicket($this);
}
```

They have to be associated with each other within the setters (or some other way) for cascade persist to work.